# How Parent and Child constructors initialize the properties of one created Child object?

Tags: java, inheritance

As I know, when a child class extends a parent class and child object is created, the child class constructor invokes automatically the parent class constructor using super() implicitly.

There will be only one object created and two constructors working on it, the parent constructor initializes the properties that are inherited from parent class and child constructor will initialize the properties that are specific to the child class.

Please check the below example:

```
public class P
{
    int x;

    P(){
        x = 1;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class C extends P
{
    int x;

    C(){
        x = 2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
        System.out.println("c.x: " + c.x);
        System.out.println("c.getX(): " + c.getX());
    }
}
```

---

Outputs:

```
c.x: 2
c.getX(): 1
```

I am very confused, there is only one object created, and that object cannot contain 2 properties with same name, and if child class hides the parent variable: 'x', why we have two different outputs?

Child and Parent are reading from one object, how this one object has 2 different x with 2 different outputs!

Parent is reading x from which object?
Child is reading x from which object?
there is only one object that has one x, how this x has different output?

Please help.

Comment: Child is reading x from Parent is which reading x how this x has different output.

Comment: "and that object cannot contain 2 properties with same name" - it can, actually.

Comment: "*there is only one object that has one x*" One object with two `x`s.

Answer (score 0):

> and that object cannot contain 2 properties with same name

You're mistaken. They actually *can*, but then `x` of `C` is said to *hide* `x` of `P`. This is defined in the Java Language Specification (JLS), [§ 8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3):

> If a class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to **hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses**, and superinterfaces of the class.

<sup>(Emphasis mine.)</sup>

This has two implications:

1. You can refer to `P.x` from within `C` by using `super` (JLS [§ 15.11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2)):

   ```java
   class C extends P {

       int x;

       void test() {
           System.out.println(super.x);
       }
   }
   ```
2. You cannot refer to `P.x` from another class or a static context (also JLS [§ 15.11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2)):

   ```java
   class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("P.x: " + c.super.x); // Won't work
       }
   }
   ```

---

Here's an example showing that `C` can refer to two different `x`s:

```java
class Parent {

    int x;

    Parent() {
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

```java
class Child extends Parent {

    int x;

    Child() {
        x = 2;
    }

    void printBothXs() {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(super.x);
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child c = new Child();
    c.printBothXs();
}
```

[<kbd>Run with ideone</kbd>](https://ideone.com/sz7BSL)

Comment: external code doesn't exist ;) Or the other way round: if you think that the example is helpful, you might consider adding it here.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for pointing that out. New ideone code somehow defaults to visibility 'secret', instead of 'public'. Anyhow, I've included the code itself.

Comment: thanks :) The major problem with external code is less the current visibility than the _future_ visibility/existence, IMO